Android Gboard password suggestion from associated domains
Hello I'm trying get Gboard to suggest a password saved to google password manager from an associated domain.
I have followed the steps in "App Links Assistants"

my assetlinks.json content

[
  {
    "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.get_login_creds"],
    "target": {
      "namespace": "android_app",
      "package_name": "app.package.name",
      "sha256_cert_fingerprints": [
        "my:app:key"
      ]
    }
  }
]


Manifest Intent Filter


      <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="domain.com" />
            </intent-filter>



App links work successfully, and app is associated with selected domain per App Links Assistant.
However I'm not seeing a password suggestion from Gboard for the associated domain, Gboard is generating passwords for other apps and I have checked their asset link files including their relation value and it's the same as mine.
I'm left wondering if my changes need to be pushed to the playstore in order for Gboard password suggestion to work.
